# python virtualenv not being activated

Tags: python, virtualenv

So i am creating virtualenv by issuing following command

```
[  8:37pm ]  [ xyz@ZYZ-MBP.local:~/repos/python ]
 $ virtualenv projectname
New python executable in /Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Then i am issuing following command to *activate* the environment

```
[  8:37pm ]  [ xyz@ZYZ-MBP.local:~/repos/python ]
 $ source projectname/bin/activate
[  8:37pm ]  [ xyz@ZYZ-MBP.local:~/repos/python ]
```

But instead of getting prompt which says `(projectname)$ ...` i just get regular prompt with `$` sign.

What i am missinghere? How can i fix this issue?

---

**Update**

here is the output of `project -m site` command. i ran this command after `activating` the venv

```
[  8:56pm ]  [ xyz@xyzs-MBP.local:~/repos/python ]
 $ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python27.zip',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/xyz/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/xyz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

Comment: Check `python -m site` in the venv; does it include the new site packages? Could just be a clever PS1 value in the way

Comment: Could you show us the `PATH` environment variable? That `(projectname)` is a terminal-based one, you need to config it. It doesn't mean it doesn't work without that sign.

Comment: @Sraw my thoughts too. Checking the site packages will at least tell if its overriding the system python interpreter.

Comment: can you guys elaborate more? where should i run `python -m site` command? should i run it in `projectname` folder?

Comment: Python site module can be run anywhere. It asks the python interpreter where it sources all of its packages from. When you activate a venv it will change the interpreter for `python` and `pip` to ones hooked up to the site packages of the virtual environment. As you can see here, it includes the site packages for your venv  `projectname`. i.e. the last line tells you this `/Users/xyz/repos/python/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. So it looks like it's just the prompt that isn't being set.

Comment: thanks. any reasons why i am not getting that specific prompt?

Comment: Is it possible that `$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` is set in your environment before running `source projectname/bin/activate`?  That is one thing that will suppress the prompt.

Comment: `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` gave me `1` output.

Comment: Then if you `unset VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` before calling `source projectname/bin/activate`, I believe you should get the expected `(projectname)` prompt.

Comment: Worked. But now i am having another weird issue. i sourced into my new environment. after confirming (using `python -m site` commands that i am in), I did `pip install slackclient`. The installation worked fine. then i wrote a small python script where i am importing `slackclient` but python interpreter is giving me error that module not found

Comment: Package name and module name do not always match.  In this case, it appears that the module name (what you need to `import`) is `slack`.